# Initialising objects with functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

Lets say I have a class `A` like this:

```
export class A extends Observable {

    constructor(
        public id: string
    ) { super(); }

    public testCallFunction() {
        return "Function called on object with id " + this.id;
    }
}
```

I can initialise an array of `A` like this and the function is exposed:

```
this.data = [new A("1"), new A("2")];
```

When I initialise the array like this, it does not let me call the function due to "type error":

```
this.data = [{ "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }] as Array<A>;
// ERROR TypeError: a.testCallFunction is not a function
```

Is there anyway I can use the second way of initialising the array and also expose the functions?

Where can I read more about this behaviour?

Playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=G7b4f4&v=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you use an Object literal, you have to create all the properties and methods of A, before typescript can accept that your object is of type A.

This is why you create intances with `new`. Now you automatically get all the properties and methods.

```
class A {

    private id: string

    constructor(id: string) { 
        this.id = id
    }

    public testCallFunction() {
        return "Function called on A instance"
    }
}

class Test {
    private data: A[];

    constructor() {

        this.data = [new A("1"), new A("2")]

        // typescript does not recognise this object 
        // as an A instance because it has no testcallFunction

        // this.data = [{ "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }]

        var a:A = this.data[0]
        a.testCallFunction()
    }
}
```

UPDATE

You can use `Object.assign()` to add properties from JSON to an existing instance.

```
class A {

    public id: string

    public testCallFunction() {
        console.log("my id is " + this.id)
    }
}

let a = new A()
let json = { "id": "1" }

Object.assign(a, json)

console.log("id is now " + a.id)
a.testCallFunction()
```

Comment: Interesting. I would expect to get a type error from `this.data = [{ "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }] as Array<A>;` then but I guess not. Nice little gotcha :)

Comment: That's because you use `as`. This is used to convert from one type to another type. When you use `as`, you overrule the default type checking! When you use `this.data:A[] = [...]` you will get type errors!

Comment: I was hoping to be able to initialise my big big json data file using the `as` syntax and still get access to the methods. Anyway to expose them manually without looping through the whole data creating `new` objects?

Comment: Do you want to create `A` instances from JSON data? You could use `Object.assign()` to add all properties from a generic object to an A instance. Or you can rewrite the A class to accept a single JSON object in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, how would I use Object.assign for this?

Comment: I added an object.assign example